# In MapBox Studio Classic (cartocss) is it possible to style a #waterway to show up at zoom levels below 8

Tags: mapbox

I'm working with Mapbox studio classic, using Mapbox Streets V6 as the vector tile source. I'm working on a project specifically related to waterways, and only larger bodies of water (#water in cartocss) show up when not zoomed in.

Is this a limitation of using this specific vector tile source?

Any ideas how to make them show up at lower zoom levels?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mapbox-streets-v6 vector dataset that ships with Mapbox Studio Classic only has certain vector data layers at each zoom level. The waterway data does not appear in this dataset at any zoom lower than 8, which is why you can't style it at any other zoom level.

Fortunately, this data comes from OpenStreetMap, so you can [add it as a custom source](https://mapbox.com/guides/source-quickstart) in Mapbox Studio Classic and style it along with the other data! There is even a [guide on grabbing this data from OpenStreetMap with Overpass Turbo](https://www.mapbox.com/guides/overpass-turbo/).

Comment: Worked great - thanks! Also, I found that if processing the actual query results is a bit big for the Overpass Turbo webapp, these are helpful: https://www.npmjs.com/package/osmtogeojson
http://overpass-api.de/